# Jest returns "Network Error" when doing a mock request with axios and msw

Tags: node.js, typescript, axios, jestjs, msw

I have been using msw and axios to test my APIs in front end (node-typescript). The APIs return valid responses when I access them through Postman.
The jest test for testing the GET API is

`server = setupServer(...mocks)`

```
server.use(
  
  rest.get(sampleUrl, (req, res, cx) => {
    return res.once(sampleResponse)})
);

server.printHandlers(); // on printing handlers, I see the sampleUrl printed

const features = await sampleMethod(param1);

expect(features).toEqual(sampleResponse);
```

On executing the above(only for a particular API) I seem to get this error

```
[MSW] Error: captured a request without a matching request handler:

  • GET sampleUrl

If you still wish to intercept this unhandled request, please create a request handler for it.
Read more: https://mswjs.io/docs/getting-started/mocks
```

The full exception is:

```
AxiosError {
  message: 'Network Error',
  name: 'AxiosError',
  code: 'ERR_NETWORK',
  config: {
    transitional: {
      silentJSONParsing: true,
      forcedJSONParsing: true,
      clarifyTimeoutError: false
    },
    adapter: [Function: xhrAdapter],
    transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
    transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
    timeout: 0,
    xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
    xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
    maxContentLength: -1,
    maxBodyLength: -1,
    env: { FormData: [Function] },
    validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
    headers: { Authorization: 'Sample Bearer auth...' },
    method: 'get',
    url: 'sampleUrl',
    data: undefined
  },
  request: XMLHttpRequestOverride {
    _events: [],
    UNSENT: 0,
    OPENED: 1,
    HEADERS_RECEIVED: 2,
    LOADING: 3,
    DONE: 4,
    onreadystatechange: null,
    onabort: [Function: handleAbort],
    onerror: [Function: handleError],
    onload: null,
    onloadend: [Function: onloadend],
    onloadstart: null,
    onprogress: null,
    ontimeout: [Function: handleTimeout],
    url: 'sampleUrl',
    method: 'GET',
    readyState: 0,
    withCredentials: false,
    status: 200,
    statusText: 'OK',
    data: '',
    response: null,
    responseType: 'text',
    responseText: null,
    responseXML: null,
    responseURL: '',
    upload: null,
    timeout: 0,
    _requestHeaders: HeadersPolyfill { _headers: [Object], _names: [Map] },
    _responseHeaders: HeadersPolyfill { _headers: {}, _names: Map(0) {} },
    async: true,
    user: undefined,
    password: undefined
  },
  response: XMLHttpRequestOverride {
    _events: [],
    UNSENT: 0,
    OPENED: 1,
    HEADERS_RECEIVED: 2,
    LOADING: 3,
    DONE: 4,
    onreadystatechange: null,
    onabort: [Function: handleAbort],
    onerror: [Function: handleError],
    onload: null,
    onloadend: [Function: onloadend],
    onloadstart: null,
    onprogress: null,
    ontimeout: [Function: handleTimeout],
    url: 'sampleUrl',
    method: 'GET',
    readyState: 0,
    withCredentials: false,
    status: 200,
    statusText: 'OK',
    data: '',
    response: null,
    responseType: 'text',
    responseText: null,
    responseXML: null,
    responseURL: '',
    upload: null,
    timeout: 0,
    _requestHeaders: HeadersPolyfill { _headers: [Object], _names: [Map] },
    _responseHeaders: HeadersPolyfill { _headers: {}, _names: Map(0) {} },
    async: true,
    user: undefined,
    password: undefined
  }
}
```

When I use a different API, the test works as expected.The test fails only for a particular GET API.

Comment: Perhaps try adding a wildcard: `'*/sampleUrl`

Comment: It may be an issue with your version of undici - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77852097/msw-handler-correctly-intercepting-request-but-still-resulting-axios-network-er/77852143#77852143

Answer (score 1):

I know this is coming in a bit late, but was having the same problem, and thought I'd share what I realised.

Is `sampleResponse` in your `rest` `res.once` the correct format? You need to make sure you're using the correct `ctx` context formats, e.g. you may want something like

```
server.use(
  rest.get(sampleUrl, (req, res, ctx) => {
    return res.once(ctx.status(200), ctx.json(sampleResponse));
  })
);
```

See the [msw docs](https://mswjs.io/docs/basics/response-resolver) for more examples of how you should use context.